# Why is my Ruby code to create this Class Method not working?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, nomethoderror

Ruby n00b here trying to create a simple method to add to the Array class, but having considerable difficulty. I'm trying to code a method that not only returns the maximum value of an integer array, but the index where it occurs as well. Here is my code:

```
class Array
    def self.maxplus(matrix)
        i = 0
        maximum = 0
        while i < matrix.length-1
            if matrix[i] > maximum
                maximum = matrix[i]
                index = i
            end
            i += 1
        end
        puts index
        puts maximum
    end
end
```

when I try to run `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8].maxplus`, I get the following compiler error:

```
undefined method 'maxplus' for [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]:Array (No Method Error)
```

I am at a loss and have been trying to figure the problem out on my for some time. Thanks so much for your help and education.

Comment: are you certain that you are invoking `maxplus` on `Array`? Or is that an instance of `Array`?

Comment: okay, I'm probably really confused. I'd like to be able to create my own method to call on any array that returns the max and the index where it occurs. i.e.,  if A = [5, 6] , then A.maxplus returns 1 and 6. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a static method for the `Array` class, i.e., `Array.maxplus(matrix)`, yet you're trying to call it on an *instance* of an `Array`.  So either call it like so:

```
Array.maxplus(matrix)
```

Or make it an instance method:

```
class Array
    def maxplus
        i = 0
        maximum = 0
        while i < self.length-1
            if self[i] > maximum
                maximum = self[i]
                index = i
            end
            i += 1
        end
        puts index
        puts maximum
    end
end

[1, 2, 3].maxplus
```

Comment: Ed S., thank you! I tried to define the method as you did above, but I didn't know how to use 'self' to refer to the matrix I was dealing with! This site rules...love the community.

Comment: Ed, I realize you were not asked to improve the code, but it's worth noting that the instance method can be simplified quite a bit, e.g., `class Array; def maxplus; maximum = max; [index(maximum), maximum]; end; end`, to be invoked `ndx, mx = [1,2,3].maxplus # ndx=>2, mx=>3`. Ice, the default receiver is `self` for the methods `max` and `index`, so there is no need to reference `self` explicitly. Nor is `self` needed in `self.length` above, though it is needed in `self[i]` and in a few other situations.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Of course, and in the real world it may be simplified to nothing as a method which *prints* the maximum value and its index is not terribly useful.  I added `self` to `length` just to further illustrate the point, but you're right, and I wouldn't use it in my own code.